# jQuery scoll animation not working for icon

Tags: jquery

I successfully implemented a jQuery animation to adjust for an offset from a fixed header for my nav links. However I added a Font Awesome icon that is linked to one of the sections (with an ID `#about`) which is the same as one of the nav links. When I click the icon, nothing happens, but clicking the nav links applies the jQuery offset.

This is the jQuery:

```
let sectionId;

$('.nav-link, .chevron').click((e) => {
  sectionId = $(e.target).attr('href');
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(sectionId).offset().top - 20
  }, 100);
});
```

HTML -- 
The jQuery works with this:

```
<a class="nav-link px-4" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
```

But not for this (lower in the page):

```
<a class="chevron" href="#about">
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-down fa-3x text-white"></i>
</a>
```

I suspect it's something to do with referring to the `href` with the same ID `#about` for both the `nav-link` and `chevron` classes. If so, is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(e.currentTarget)`

`e.target` is what triggers the event dispatcher to trigger and `e.currentTarget` is what you assigned your listener to.

```
let sectionId;
$('.nav-link, .chevron').click((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  sectionId = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(sectionId).offset().top - 20
  }, 100);
});
```

Comment: I'd also recommend using `e.preventDefault()` at the top of the function to prevent the page from jumping during animation.